# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near at line 1

Tags: php, mysql

this is my upadating script--

```
        $cno = $data[6];

        $result = mysql_query("select * 
                               from courier_details 
                               where consignment_no = '".$cno."'");


           if($result >0)
           {
                   $update = "UPDATE `courier_details`  
                   SET(`shipper_name`, `shipper_phone`, `shipper_address`, `receiver_name`, 
                       `receiver_phone`, `receiver_address`, `consignment_no`, 
                       `type_of_shippment`, `weight`, `volumetric_weight`, `packages`, 
                       `product`, `qnty`, `booking_mode`, `total_freight`, `mode`, 
                       `dept_time`, `origin`, `destination`, `pickup_date`, `pickup_time`,
                       `status`, `excepted_dly_date`, `comments`, `delivered_date`, 
                      `delivered_time`, `deboy`, `career`,`originbr`, `destinationbr`, 
                      `email`) 
                  VALUES('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]',
                         '$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]','$data[9]','$data[10]','$data[11]',
                         '$data[12]','$data[13]','$data[14]','$data[15]','$data[16]',
                         '$data[17]','$data[18]','$data[19]','$data[20]','$data[21]',
                         '$data[22]','$data[23]','$data[24]','$data[25]','$data[26]',
                         '$data[27]','$data[28]','$data[29]','$data[30]')
                  WHERE `consignment_no` = '".$cno."'";            

                   mysql_query($update) or die(mysql_error());
         }
```

there is show an error while execute code--

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

near '(`shipper_name`, `shipper_phone`, `shipper_address`, `receiver_name`, `receiver_' at line 1

Comment: Please do a minimal amount of research before posting, that's not the right syntax for update at all.

Comment: update table set() where columt_name = 'abc';                                                                I know about that if you know more then please help me.

Comment: Give space before WHERE Clause

Answer (score 1):

Your update query seems wrong.

You cannot use `UPDATE` query like `INSERT` query. Syntax should be:

```
Update TableName
Set col1=val1,
    col2=val2,
    col3=val3,
.......
```

On the other hand, `INSERT` can be used like:

```
INSERT INTO TableName
 (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (val1,val2,val3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You were mixing `update` and `insert` query you need to learn about the differences between them

**UPDATE**

```
UPDATE table_name SET field1=new-value1, field2=new-value2
[WHERE Clause]
```

**INSERT**

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (column1, column2, column3,...columnN)]  
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...valueN);
```

So your query will be like

```
"UPDATE `courier_details` SET `shipper_name` = '$data[0]', 
`shipper_phone` = '$data[1]'..... 
 WHERE `consignment_no` = '$cno'"
```

Answer (score 0):

use `mysql_num_rows()` to count number of row

this is wrong

```
if($result >0)
```

And don't use `update` query as `insert` query both are different

It would be:-

```
 $result = mysql_query("select * from courier_details where consignment_no = '" . $cno . "'");

if (mysql_num_rows() > 0) {
     $update="UPDATE table_name SET field1=value1, field2=value2";
    mysql_query($update) or die(mysql_error());
}
```